# Why does WAMP run script with similar name instead of rewriting URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

I'm trying to rewrite all requests to `index.php` and then there decide which file to include depending on the value in the `$_GET['p']` variable. For example I have a script called `update.php` in the home directory of my site called `leltar`, which I would like to be included if the opened page is `localhost/leltar/update`.

However, the problem is that the rewriting does not work because WAMP runs the script even though the `.php` extension is not in the link. The output is just the one from the script, nothing is shown from `index.php`. How can I stop WAMP from running the script with similar name? I suppose, there is something wrong with my .htaccess code as well because if I open pages other than `localhost/leltar/update`, the value of `$_GET['p']` is the string *"index.php"* all the time.

**.htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1
```

**index.php:**

```php
// ...
    switch ($_GET['p']) {
        case 'update':
            require_once('update.php');
            break;
        default:
            // something else
            break;
    }
// ...
```

*The content of `update.php` is not relevant.*

**EDIT:**
The main problem is that by default or even when I use the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` rewrite condition if there is a file with the same name as the user-friendly end of the link, WAMP somehow overrides my rewrite rules. If I put a picture named `pic.jpg` into the `www` folder and open `localhost/pic.jpg`, the image shows up, obviously. However, if I leave out the extension visiting the page `localhost/pic`, I get the same output as well (instead of getting a **404 Not Found** error because of the non-exisiting folder, I suppose).

**EDIT 2:**
On a real server there isn't any problem. If I leave out the extension a 404 error is thrown, so it's definitely a WAMP-specific thing.

Comment: Add [NC,L] to the end of the RewriteRule line, L is the flag to tell it stop checking against other rules ("Last"). NC tells it to be case insensitive.

Comment: @Enstage `L` only prevents the current iteration from going further, so it won't prevent this. `NC` isn't necessary because no characters of any specific case are being matched against.

Comment: Side note: a little known fact is that you don't absolutely need mod_rewrite to do this. The [FallbackResource](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) directive from mod_dir can do the same with less hassle.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: Unfortunately, I can't use this method either. Although, it's supposed to do the thing I want to achieve, still, if there is a file on the server with the same name (not counting the extension) as the link entered, it will try to open the file directly. Probably there is a setting in WAMP hidden somewhere which causes this behavior...

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález nice solution, will experiment with that

Comment: Regarding the update, see the comment on my answer, it sounds like you have `MultiViews` enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as [@SuperDuperApps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2493235/superduperapps) assumed, the problem was that WAMP has `MultiViews` enabled by default. Adding `Options -MultiViews` to my `.htaccess` file solved all my problems, my initial code mentioned in the question works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Rules in `.htaccess` files effectively loop until the URL does not change (because the processing is restarted each time, which means the rules are also processed again) so of course your rule loops until `p` is equal to itself.

You don't actually need `p`, you can just check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in your PHP script and that will tell you the original requested URI (not the same as `REQUEST_URI` below, which does change with each rewrite).

So just use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**But...** you probably want files that exist to be served, such as images, scripts etc. so the usual thing is to do this and check if the file exists:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Although it's more efficient to do this and list the directories with files in them that you want to be served:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:images|css|scripts)/
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Just change the list to the names of the directories that have your static files in.

**Update**

From the comments, it seems you have another rewrite that is adding `.php` to URLs, so they can work without it. In order to not rewrite them to `index.php`, I suggest putting the rewrite before this one. Otherwise, you can check if the URL exists with `.php` on the end of it like this. Perhaps combining it with the folder check rather than having two file-system checks.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:images|css|scripts)/
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

You can add specific file exceptions to the third rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:images|css|scripts)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/some/url.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/some_other_url.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: The first and last snippet works as it should, however, I can't reference any script in the home directory directly because everything gets rewritten to `index.php`, for example all the AJAX requests are broken. I want to be able to reference the existing files directly, but if I change my `.htaccess` file to the second snippet and open `localhost/leltar/update`, it's essentially the same as if I had opened the page `localhost/leltar/update.php` directly. Nothing from `index.php` is displayed, nothing gets rewritten, the `update.php` script is run directly, which shouldn't be run on it's own.

Comment: Your message is a little unclear, but I added an update which will hopefully help you work out what you need to solve it. You can also add file exceptions to the third solution, which I provided information on.

Comment: Still not what I need. WAMP somehow by default adds extensions to the URLs. If I have a file with the same name as the URL, the browser opens it instead of throwing a 404 error for trying to access non-existing url. If I open `localhost/pic`, the image `localhost/pic.jpg` gets opened. But it can be a `.png`, `.pdf`, `.php`, basically anything – it does not matter. So there is a hidden setting somewhere that overrides my rewrite rules and adds extensions to the links. The code works without problem on real server and throws an error if I leave out the extension. See my edited question.

Comment: It sounds like you have `MultiViews` enabled. Try adding `Options -MultiViews` to your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem. It seems like WAMP has `MultiViews` enabled by default. Again, thank you for helping me out, I had no idea what was happening... :)